# PHP unexpected ; i cant figure out

Tags: php

For some reason this will result in an unexpected ; in line 4. I cant figure out why this wont work. If I remove the ; it will result in an unexpected T_VARIABLE in line 5.

```
<?php
    findMostFreq($arr)
    {
      $y = arsort($arr);
       $freq = array();

       foreach($y as $v)
       {
           if((array_key_exists($v, $freq))
            $freq[$v]++;

            else 
            $freq[$v] = 1;
       }

    }
}
?>
```

Comment: `if((array_key_exists($v, $freq))` - extra `(` at the beginning

Comment: Why are you not simply using [array_count_values()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php)?

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation of [arsort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.arsort.php) is wrong also you've some syntax error.

**arsort:**

> Returns **TRUE** on success or **FALSE** on failure. But you're
>   expecting array here.

```
<?php
function findMostFreq($arr)
{
    arsort($arr);
    $freq = array();

    foreach ($arr as $v) {
        if (array_key_exists($v, $freq)) {
            $freq[$v]++;
        } else {
            $freq[$v] = 1;
        }
    }
    return $freq;
}    

$arr = array("d" => "lemon", "a" => "orange", "b" => "banana", "c" => "apple","m" => "lemon");
$result = findMostFreq($arr);
print '<pre>';
print_r($result);
print '</pre>';
```

?>

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [orange] => 1
    [lemon] => 2
    [banana] => 1
    [apple] => 1
)
```

**DEMO:** https://eval.in/981994

*By the way If you just want which array value occurs most/how many time i.e which value occurs how many times in the array*, try using [array_count_values()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php)

Comment: @Cobra_Fast yes I've seen the syntax error, I'm going to fix that syntax error

Comment: @Cobra_Fast Fix that syntax issue.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone yes you're ri8 `array_count_values()` will do the trick on my particular array example

Comment: Im not sure what you mean, both will break on multi-dimensional. Was just pointing it out. Hardly worth reinventing the wheel, when the code will be run in C and be much faster.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
function findMostFreq($arr)
{
    arsort($arr);
    $freq = array();

    foreach ($arr as $v) {
        if (array_key_exists($v, $freq)) {
            $freq[$v]++;
        } else {
            $freq[$v] = 1;
        }
    }
}
findMostFreq($someArray);
```

Comment: When you answer with a corrected version of a questions code, please always explain what changes you made.